# In C, how to set the delimiter of scanf to anything that is not alphabetic?

Tags: c, regex, range, scanf, delimiter

Is there a way to set the delimiter of scanf to anything that is not alphabetic?

I mean, say I have an input from stdin: abc123def. Technically it is only one string, but I want to treat it as 2 strings delimited by something non-alphabetic (123 in this case).

I found a way to set custom delimiters but here, it is a huge range (numeric characters, special characters, spaces, tabs... anything not in the range A..Za..z).

Just as an example, here is something I want to do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

char str[100];

while (scanf("%s", str) == 1)
    {
    printf("%s\n", str);
    }

return(0);
}
```

The above code uses only whitespace as delimiter (I think). But I want it to use any non-alphabetic character to use as delimiter. So when the input is:

Hi12There..Hello

It will output:
Hi
There
Hello

Update: Ok, I found a solution. It uses the strtok function which does the job, but in a different way. Here's how the code looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

int i, len;
char str[100], *word;

while (gets(str))
    {
    len = strlen(str);
    for (i=0; i < len; i++)     // Replacing anything non alphabetic with space
        {
        if ( !(((str[i] >= 'A') && (str[i] <= 'Z')) || ((str[i] >= 'a') && (str[i] <= 'z'))) )
            {
            str[i] = ' ';
            }
        }

    word = strtok(str, " ");
    while (word != NULL)
        {
        printf("%s\n", word);
        word = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
    }

return(0);
}
```

It does the job, but I was wondering if I could have done it directly while taking the strings from stdin.

Cheers.

Comment: Did you mean `A..Za..z`? The set of characters `ABab` isn't very "huge".

Comment: is 'Ä' or 'ß' a special character or a normal letter in your case study?

Comment: Silly typo.... maybe I need to go to elementary school again... Yeah A..Za..z is exactly what I mean :D

Comment: Umm no those characters won't be in the input. By special characters, I mean periods, commas, slashes etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the character sequence format specifier:

```
char s1[128], s2[128];

if(sscanf("abc123def", "%127[A-Za-z]%*[0-9]%127[A-Za-z]", s1, s2) == 2)
{
  printf("got '%s' and '%s'\n", s1, s2);
}
```

Comment: Instead of `%*d`, in the middle I would go with `%*[0-9]`.

Comment: @cnicutar Sure, why not. Could also use `%*[^A-Za-z]`, perhaps.

Comment: Well I actually don't know how many words will be in the string. So I have to use a loop (see the example I added). Will this solution work in a loop? If so, can you please give an example. I am a beginner though, so please make it easy :D Thanks.

Comment: You can do it in a loop using `%*[^A-Za-z]%127[A-Za-z]` on each go. The first part will get rid of anything non-alphabetic and the second part will actually store the string you want.

Comment: Can you please give an example with a while loop?